# Could not find method externalNativeBuild() for arguments

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, build.gradle, ndk-build, android-studio-2.2

i'm trying to integrate the ndkBuild functionality into an existing android studio project, using the new android studio 2.2 , in order to enable c++ debugging etc.
i have tried out one of the ndk example projects which android studio 2.2 offers, which works perfectly fine. However, when i try to run the gradle commands in my own project, i get this error message:

*Error:(73, 0) Could not find method externalNativeBuild() for arguments [build_c6heui1f67l8o1c3ifgpntw6$_run_closure2$_closure9@4329c1c9] on project  ':core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.*

By following this description 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds
i ended up with a gradle script which includes the following commands:

```
externalNativeBuild{
    ndkBuild{
        path "$projectDir/jni/Android.mk"
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
      arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=$projectDir/jni/Application.mk"
      abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi","arm64-v8a","x86"
      cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
    }
}
```

Did i perhaps miss out on something here with the project setup?
I have set the **Android NDK location** properly under

*File -> Project Structure ... -> SDK Location  -> Android NDK location*

in my android studio.

Anything else i might have forgotton?

Has anyone run into a similar problem before?

Advice would be much appreciated =)

Comment: Did you put the externalNativeBuild inside of the android{} block?

Comment: yes I did, so it can't be the error source

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just had this error myself. In your root `build.gradle`, make sure that gradle is set to at least version 2.2.0:

So you should have the following in `buildscript {...}`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: What about `gradle:3.2.1`? Still getting the error using this version.

Answer (score 3):

Suggested by *Kun Ming Xies* answer, I have separated my `cmake` part in two to get rid of the annoying error:

> Could not find method arguments() for arguments [-DREVISION=1.3.1] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions.

The first part in `defaultConfig` contains the configuration (command line arguments for CMake and C++ flags), and the second contains the path to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
def revision = "1.3.1"
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    versionCode = ...
    versionName "${revision}"
    externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
        arguments "-DREVISION=${revision}"
        cppFlags '-fexceptions', '-frtti', '-std=c++11'
      }
    }
  }

  buildTypes { }

  lintOptions { }

  externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
      path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang'
            }
        }
    }
```